# Force/limit android wifi to use the 2.5 Ghz Band

Tags: android

I'd like to limit the use of WI-FI band to the 2.4 GHZ and disable the the 5GHZ band on my android PDA symbole TC70 or any other android device. so any one who will use this device must use only 2.4 GHZ. how can i do this programmatically please

Comment: I seriously doubt that is possible without some highly customised kernel and Android code. Out of curiosity, why don't you want people using the 5GHz band?

Comment: simply because it's prohibited in our country, i'd like to simplify the use of the pda so when the wifi is enabled automatically the 2.5 GHz band is checked. Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Zebra Technologies's Android EMDK](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/community/android/emdk) to select which RF Band you want to enable, in particular you can use the [WiFi Profile settings](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/docs/DOC-2290).

In details, you create the needed profile in Android Studio's [EMDK Wizard](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/docs/DOC-2169) and use the [Profile API](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/docs/DOC-2991) to apply the configuration at runtime. You can use the [Persistence Profile](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/docs/DOC-2288) to make this setup "Enterprise Reset" resistant (so that only a factory reset restore the original setup).

This solution works only on Zebra Technologies Enterprise-ready Android devices, like the [TC70](http://www.zebra.com/tc70), [TC75](http://www.zebra.com/tc75), [TC55](http://www.zebra.com/tc55), etc.

Comment: unrelated but I have some TC70 guns that do not have GMS on them, android 4.4.3 version, best way to get GMS on them? I've tried doing google play and google play services apks from apkmirror with little success...

Comment: Best way is to download it from [Zebra support website](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/mobile-computers/handheld/tc70.html). TC70 is now available with Android v4.4.3 (KitKat) and v5.1 (Lollipop) both with and without GMS.  To download a new system image you need to have a valid maintenance contract ([Zebra OneCare](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/services/run/support-services/zebra-onecare.html))